# Angular 2: Passing form data from child to parent only if it is valid

Tags: components, angular2-forms, interaction

I have an angular reactive form in the child component and **Submit** button in the parent component. By default, **Submit** button in the parent component is disabled. I need a mechanism through which I should be able to check the form status in the child component, whether it is **valid** or **invalid**.

The moment status **valid** becomes **true**, the button in parent component should be enabled.

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

my solution

**app.child.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    template: `...`
})
export class AppChild {
    form: FormGroup;
}
```

**app.parent.html**

```
<app-child #child></app-child>

<button [disabled]="child.form.invalid">Submit</button>
```

Comment: This method works fine. I also used (click) and passed the form to a method in parent and accessed child form in parent. Is this the best method or is there any other approach with better performance?

Comment: you can use ValidationService for that purpose.
create your own Service `ValidatorService` and some how you notify the `parentComponent` to check and `emit` the validation status to that service and `subscribe` from the `parentComponent` to that status if there is any change it will be catch on a `callback function` and do what you want

Answer (score 0):

1. you need subscribe for valueChanges event in your child component, in which you can emit the value of your form,

   this.formname.valueChange.subscribe(status=>{
      this.valueEmit.emit(this.formname.valid)
   });
2. In you parent comonents template check status of that emitted event.